# Importing data into mysql using fgetcsv() and null values are stored as zeros

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a csv file i'm trying to write into mysql table.

```
file.csv
id,name,age,job
5,John Smith,34,Janitor
7,Jane Smith,,Teacher
9,Jim Bob,23,Coach

table
CREATE TABLE `table` (
 `id` smallint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `name` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `age` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `job` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My issue is that the null value for Jane Smith's age is being inserted into my MySQL table as 0, despite the `age` default being NULL. I'm using the following fgetcsv() PHP.

```
$f = '/home/file.csv';
$file = fopen($f,'r');
fgetcsv($file); // skips 1st line with headers
while (($data = fgetcsv($file,0,",")) !== FALSE) {
  if (array(null) !== $data) {

  $id = $data[0];
  $name = $data[1];
  $age = $data[2];
  $job = $data[3];

  $bind_params = array(
   ':id' => $id,
   ':name' => $name,
   ':age' => $age,
   ':job' => $job
  );

  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (id, name, age, job) VALUES (:id, :name, :age, :job)");
  $stmt->execute($bind_params);

  }
}
```

I've read http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html at length but I can't figure it out.  I've substituted "NULL", "", "\N", NULL, and \N between the ,, but I haven't gotten any different results. I've also tried by explicitly typing the optional parameters for fgetcsv() as shown in the example on php.net.

```
array fgetcsv ( resource $handle [, int $length = 0 [, string $delimiter = "," [, string $enclosure = '"' [, string $escape = "\\" ]]]] )
```

What am I missing!?  Thank you.

**Additional Info:**
I prefer this be a php/fgetcsv solution and not a pure MySQL solution, as the data above is only a snapshot (there are 99 columns in total) and many of the columns are inputs into php calculations before being inserted into other tables.

Comment: As said in manual all values binded in `pdo->execute` are treated as strings. That's why you have  to write some code to check if your age field is set and correct query.

Comment: @u_mulder I've added the PDO query to the question. What you say makes sense, but how would an empty value (,, in csv terms) even after enclosed by single or double quotes as a string not be interpreted as a true NULL value? Are you saying to not use a ::bindParam and instead use something else?  Thanks for your input.

Comment: http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.null.php Empty value != NULL. You can `var_dump($age)` and definitely it will be an empty string.

Comment: @u_mulder Your comment about empty != null helped me come up with a workable solution, which I posted at the bottom of the question. Wasn't thinking clearly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Empty values in a csv are read by PHP's fgetcsv() as empty strings, not as true NULL values. Re-assign only those variables that are empty strings (via if() statement) to NULL values before binding variables (for PDO) and inserting into MySQL table.

After input from @u_mulder, I wrapped each variable in an if statement that looks for empty strings, and if empty string is true, then assign that variable value = null. Since I have 99 columns, i'll put this into a for() loop to get all the columns.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=99; $i++) {
  if($data[$i] === "") { $data[$i] = null; }
}
```

I implemented this, and it worked exactly as I initially needed.

**edit**
I updated code to use the === instead of just ==.  I found that the double equal sign was converting zeros into null values. Since I only wanted exactly empty strings, the third equal sign is needed.